# Tomcat, JAR in server.loader not loaded

Tags: tomcat, classloader, tomcat8

We are trying to use Redisson for tomcat session management, for that we are following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/redis-based-tomcat-session-management) article. When we add the Redission JAR in the Tomcat lib folder it was conflicting with our application JAR and creates `java.lang.LinkageError`. So to avoid that I tried to put the Redission JAR in a separate folder named "server-lib" and configured that folder in `server.loader` of `catalina.properties`, my understanding was that by doing this the Redisson JAR will be available only for Tomcat  but when I start Tomcat it is throwing class not found exception for Redission classes.
My question is why the classes are not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Create directory in `${catalina.home}/lib/` and place the Redission JAR.

Configure the path in the `common.loader` of `catalina.properties`